# Redux-form and error animation

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

How to add animation to the errors, which appear near input fields in redux-form.

I have not found any ways to do it.

```
export default ({input, label, meta}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <label>{label}</label>
            <input {...input} style={{marginBottom: '5px'}}/>
            <div className="red-text" style={{marginBottom: '20px'}}>
                { meta.touched && meta.error }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add

`opacity: this.state.show ? 1 : 0`

to your error message div, then use css Transition for animation, e.g. :

```
MsTransition: 'all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55)',
WebkitTransition: 'all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55)',
transition: 'all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55)',
```

So any time when the message show will run the animation